# ASP.NET MVC Async Controllers and Active MQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asynchronous, activemq-classic, spring.net

Scenario: User saves an Order

Things need to be done to complete Order workflow:

- Save order to Database with a flag 'not acknowledged'.
- Push order to Active MQ and listen for acknowledgement message due to appear in another Q. Usually it takes from 1 minutes to unknown time to receive acknowledgement message in the other Q.
- When I receive acknowledgement update flag in Database.

I don't want user to wait until acknowledgement message received, so once Order saved successfully to the database user can navigate away from the web page. Currently I'm saving orders to Database using an Ajax post method and planning to call an Async action when saving to Database is successful. This Async action is suppose to work with Active MQ and wait indefinitely till it receive an acknowledgement.

Question: Is Async controllers is the right choice here? Or shall I write a Windows services which polls for the acknowledgement Q and update Database accordingly. Main objective to reduce complexity and maintenance overhead.